# Absolute positioned element width issue

Tags: css, width, css-position

I've following DOM structure

```
<div>
    <span>/* comment action */</span>       //float:left
    <span>/* like action */</span>          //float:left
    <span>/* other actions                  //float:right; position:relative;
        <ul>                //position:absolute;
            <li>Set due date</li>
            <li>Delete</li>
        </ul>
    </span>
</div>
```

The problem is, the width of list item is set to width of longest word. I want each list item to appear in one line (like block) and maximum width should as of longest list item, and show them one below other.

Here are some screen shots that will give much better idea.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooEVd.jpg (max width of word "Options")

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kqAY.jpg (max width of word "time")

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScxFh.jpg (max width of word "Setduetime" when removed spaces)

How can I fix this? (I don't want to specify specific width to `ul`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@Bongs; write like this:

```
ul{white-space:nowrap}
```

Comment: You are pretty fast. It solved the issue. Stackoverflow not allowing me to mark as answer so early. :D Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: one thing for a proper markup is that never put block element inside an inline element. ul is a block element & span is an inline element.

Comment: :D gotcha... Thanks once again for the tip. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you absolutely position the ul tag? That's causing you the problem with the width.

Comment: The requirement is like that.